# modify sign of numbers in two different columns of an RDD in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working on `PySpark` and I have a `RDD` which when printed looks like this:

```
[(-10.1571, -2.361), (-19.2108, 6.99), (10.1571, 4.47695), (22.5611, 20.360), (13.1668, -2.88), ....]
```

As you can see each element in this `RDD` has two data. Now what I want to do is check if the signs of two data are different then reverse the sign of 2nd data to match the first data. For example - in `(-19.2108, 6.99)` the signs of two data are different so I want to reverse the sign of `6.99` to make it `-6.99` so that it matches sign of 1st data. But sign of data in `(-10.1571, -2.361)` and in `(22.5611, 20.360)` are same so no sign reversal in them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just essentially a python list of tuples, just check if the first element, you don't actually care what the second is just just need to match the first :

```
l = [(-10.1571, -2.361), (-19.2108, 6.99), (10.1571, 4.47695), (22.5611, 20.360), (13.1668, -2.88)]

l[:] = [(a, -abs(b)) if a < 0 else (a, abs(b))for a, b in l]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[(-10.1571, -2.361), (-19.2108, -6.99), (10.1571, 4.47695), (22.5611, 20.36), (13.1668, 2.88)]
```

Looking at the docs map might do the trick:

```
rdd1.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], -abs(tup[1])) if tup[0] < 0 else (tup[0], abs(tup[1])))
```

Comment: It is not just python list of tuples. It is an `RDD`. I get `TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable`

Comment: Ah ok, I will have a gander at the docs and see how it works, what is the name of your rdd?

Comment: Try the map, I am kind of flying blind here as I don't have it installed

Comment: lol, good  I knew the logic was correct, the rest was guesswork !